# Entries search query by 2 custom fields

Tags: craft3, entries, custom-field

So I have a Entry type that has two custom fields on it. Both fields are integer fields. I'd like to make a query in PHP that gets the entries by two custom fields, both of which are integer values. Here is my code so far:

```
    $query = [
        'year' => $year,
        'quarter' => $quarter,
    ];
    $seasonBoxes = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
                 ->section('boxes')
                 ->search($query)
                 ->orderBy('dateCreated asc')
                 ->all();
```

Please note: $year is independent of the entry creation date so I can't use the date filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields in craft that are not element is query by something called element criteria model.
In twig you do:

```
{% set result = craft.entries({
       section: 'boxes'
       orderBy: 'dateCreated asc'
       year: year,
       quarter： quarter
}).all() %}
```

In php

```
 $query = [
        'year' => $year,
        'quarter' => $quarter,
    ];
 $seasonBoxesQueryObject = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
                 ->section('boxes')
                 ->orderBy('dateCreated asc');
 $seasonBoxesQueryObject->year = $query['year'];
 $seasonBoxesQueryObject->quarter = $query['quarter'];
 $seasonBoxes = $seasonBoxesQueryObject->all();
```

Comment: Thanks Parry! This code works great!